# Scipy cosine similarity vs sklearn cosine similarity

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, cosine-similarity

I noticed that both `scipy` and `sklearn` have a cosine similarity/cosine distance functions. I wanted to test the speed for each on pairs of vectors:

```py
setup1 = "import numpy as np; arrs1 = [np.random.rand(400) for _ in range(60)];arrs2 = [np.random.rand(400) for _ in range(60)]"
setup2 = "import numpy as np; arrs1 = [np.random.rand(400) for _ in range(60)];arrs2 = [np.random.rand(400) for _ in range(60)]"

import1 = "from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity"
stmt1 = "[float(cosine_similarity(arr1.reshape(1,-1), arr2.reshape(1,-1))) for arr1, arr2 in zip(arrs1, arrs2)]"

import2 = "from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine"
stmt2 = "[float(1 - cosine(arr1, arr2)) for arr1, arr2 in zip(arrs1, arrs2)]"

import timeit
print("sklearn: ", timeit.timeit(stmt1, setup=import1 + ";" + setup1, number=1000))
print("scipy:   ", timeit.timeit(stmt2, setup=import2 + ";" + setup2, number=1000))
```

```
sklearn:  11.072769448000145
scipy:    1.9755544730005568
```

`sklearn` runs almost 10 times slower than `scipy` (even if you remove the array reshape for the sklearn example and generate data that's already in the right shape). Why is one significantly slower than the other?

Comment: I am not familiar with inner workings of `sklearn` or `scipy`; however, beside the fact that you are reshaping the arrays in one experiment and not in the other, I don't think it's a fair comparison because the `cosine_similarity` computes pairwise cosine distance of all the samples in the two input arrays (although you are invoking it on arrays of one sample), but the `cosine` function in `scipy` works only on 1D-arrays and therefore might have a much more efficient implementation.

Comment: @today Even if you get rid of the array reshaping (create the arrays using `np.random.rand(1, 400)` instead of `np.random.rand(400)` to prevent the reshape), sklearn is still slower. I suspect the fact that sklearn is designed for 2d-arrays might have something to do with it, but still, the performance difference is quite a lot.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section, I don't think the comparison is fair mainly because the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` is designed to compare pairwise distance/similarity of the samples in the given input 2-D arrays. On the other hand, `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` is designed to compute cosine distance of two 1-D arrays.

Maybe a more fair comparison is to use `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` vs. `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`, where both computes pairwise distance of samples in the given arrays. However, to my surprise, that shows the sklearn implementation is much faster than the scipy implementation (which I don't have an explanation for that currently!). Here is the experiment:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
y = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

def sklearn_cosine():
    return cosine_similarity(x, y)

def scipy_cosine():
    return 1. - cdist(x, y, 'cosine')

# Make sure their result is the same.
assert np.allclose(sklearn_cosine(), scipy_cosine())
```

And here is the timing result:

```
%timeit sklearn_cosine()
10 loops, best of 3: 74 ms per loop

%timeit scipy_cosine()
1 loop, best of 3: 752 ms per loop
```

Comment: I'm doing some work with cosine similarity at the moment. Scipy appears to run the job in a couple of Python loops, whereas Sklearn appears to use vectorized functions on the entire matrix. If you're doing a really small job, it will actually be quicker to use Scipy, but if both X and Y are large, you'll want Sklearn