# Calculate cosine similarity for between all cases in a dataframe fast

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nlp, linear-algebra

I'm working on an NLP project  where I have to compare the similarity between many sentences
E.G. from this dataframe:

[image]

The first thing I tried was to make a join of the dataframe with itself to get the bellow format and compare row by row:

[image]

The problem with this that I get out of memory quickly for big medium/big datasets,
e.g. for a 10k rows join I will get 100MM rows which I can not fit in ram

My current aproach is to iterate over the dataframe with as:

```
final = pd.DataFrame()

### for each row 
for i in range(len(df_sample)):

    ### select the corresponding vector to compare with 
    v =  df_sample[df_sample.index.isin([i])]["use_vector"].values
    ### compare all cases agains the selected vector
    df_sample.apply(lambda x:  cosine_similarity_numba(x.use_vector,v[0])  ,axis=1)

    ### kept the cases with a similarity over a given th, in this case 0.6
    temp = df_sample[df_sample.apply(lambda x:  cosine_similarity_numba(x.use_vector,v[0])  ,axis=1) > 0.6]  
    ###  filter out the base case 
    temp = temp[~temp.index.isin([i])]
    temp["original_question"] = copy.copy(df_sample[df_sample.index.isin([i])]["questions"].values[0])
    ### append the result     
    final = pd.concat([final,temp])
```

But this aproach is not fast either.
How can I improve the performance of this process?

Answer (score 7):

One possible trick you may employ is to switch from sparse tfidf representation to dense word embeddings from Facebook's [`fasttext`](https://fasttext.cc/):

```
import fasttext
# wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-crawl/cc.en.300.bin.gz
model = fasttext.load_model("./cc.en.300.bin")
```

Then you can proceed to calculate cosine similarity with more space efficient, context aware and better performing (?) dense word embeddings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"questions":["This is a question",
                                "This is a similar questin",
                                "And this one is absolutely different"]})

df["vecs"] = df["questions"].apply(model.get_sentence_vector)

from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
# only pairwise distance with itself
# vectorized, no doubling data
out = pdist(np.stack(df['vecs']), metric="cosine")
cosine_similarity = squareform(out)
print(cosine_similarity)
```

---

```
[[0.         0.08294727 0.25305626]
 [0.08294727 0.         0.23575631]
 [0.25305626 0.23575631 0.        ]]
```

Note as well, on top of memory efficiency, you also gain about [10x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490351/scipy-cosine-similarity-vs-sklearn-cosine-similarity#:%7E:text=sklearn%20runs%20almost%2010%20times,already%20in%20the%20right%20shape) speed increase due to using cosine similarity from `scipy`.

Another possible trick is to cast your similarity vectors from default `float64` to `float32` or `float16`:

```
df["vecs"] = df["vecs"].apply(np.float16)
```

which will give you both speed and memory gains.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote an answer to a problem similar to yours yesterday, which is [Top-K Cosine Similarity rows in a dataframe of pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65402052/cosine-similarity-rows-in-a-dataframe-of-pandas/65419028#65419028)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

data = {"use_vector": [[-0.1, -0.2, 0.3], [0.1, -0.2, -0.3], [-0.1, 0.2, -0.3]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("Data: \n{}\n".format(df))

vectors = []
for v in df['use_vector']:
    vectors.append(v)
vectors_num = len(vectors)
A=np.array(vectors)
# Get similarities matrix, value for each pair at corresponding index of upper triangle of matrix
similarities = cosine_similarity(A)
# Set symmetrical(repetitive) and diagonal(similarity to self) to -2
similarities[np.tril_indices(vectors_num)] = -2
print("Similarities: \n{}\n".format(similarities))
```

Outputs:

```
Data: 
          use_vector
0  [-0.1, -0.2, 0.3]
1  [0.1, -0.2, -0.3]
2  [-0.1, 0.2, -0.3]

Similarities:
[[-2.         -0.42857143 -0.85714286]  # vector 0 & 1, 2
 [-2.         -2.          0.28571429]  # vector 1 & 2
 [-2.         -2.         -2.        ]]
```